# Will my deeds be valid if I still have a painting of a lady?

Tags: deeds

A few years ago I painted on a canvas a portrait of a lady. I didn't know it was haram to draw/paint humans until my parents told me that it's haram and I have to paint over the lady (totally covering her in white paint) and paint something else like flowers. Years past and I completely forgot about this painting which is sitting near a corner of a room in the house (not my bedroom).

My question is: Will my past good deeds (charity, prayer, fasting, ...etc) be valid even though I had that painting of the lady in the house?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be valid?

Comment: They wouldn't be valid because there's a portrait of a girl in the house. Isn't that haram?

Comment: And what makes you think that doing haram things make these invalid? Let alone when you didn't even do that intentionally but rather out of ignorance.